# One article for two related nouns?

Tags: ellipsis

I am wondering if a single article can be used for two nouns.

I came across an article on [NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1986/01/27/style/dating-game-and-the-check-who-pays.html), and encountered *one single indefinite article* used for *two nouns.*

> Despite changing sexual mores, it's clear that many men and women still expect the man to pay, particularly on ***a*** first and second date. That seems to be especially true outside the Northeast, where sex roles remain more traditional.

One article for two nouns is possible? Why not writing it **again** for the second noun? Like - *"....particularly on **a first date and a second date**. That seems..."*

Based on this, I want to say

> "A first and a second layer" or "a first layer and a second layer"

instead of...

> "A first and second layer"

Is that okay?